# MySQL get all characters before specific character, If not then whole value

Tags: mysql

I need to make a query in which I have to get the string before the specific character. In my case its dot(.). And if there isn't any dot, then whole value should get returned.

If values are `Titanic.Movie` and `Avatar`, then expected output is `Titanic` and `Avatar`.

What I tried is giving me the substring before dot(.), but if there isn't any dot then it's returning blank value.

```
SELECT 
    LEFT(movie, INSTR(movie, '.') - 1)
FROM
    movie_list;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [**`SUBSTRING_INDEX`**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index):

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(movie, '.', 1) movie
FROM movie_list;
```